# Creating a Global Temporary Table Using Execute Immediate

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a temp table in oracle apex with some dynamic SQL and it's been a struggle.  The goal is to be able to select some items from a checkbox group and create a temp table where the checked items are column names.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE
  c_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P31_PARTS,'EMPNO');
  l_rows VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P31_CRITERIA,1);
  l_cols_arr  apex_t_varchar2;
  cols_arr_size integer;
  l_rows_arr  apex_t_varchar2; 
  rows_arr_size integer;
  
BEGIN
    l_cols_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_cols, p_sep => ':');
    l_rows_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_rows, p_sep => ':');
    cols_arr_size := l_cols_arr.count;
    rows_arr_size := l_rows_arr.count;

    FOR i in 1..cols_arr_size
    LOOP
        l_cols_arr(i) := REPLACE(l_cols_arr(i), ' ', '_');
    END LOOP;

    c_query := 'CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_view (Criteria_Name varchar2(4000) NULL, ';
    FOR i in 1..(cols_arr_size - 1)
    LOOP
        c_query := c_query||l_cols_arr(i)||' varchar2(4000) NULL, ';
    END LOOP;
    c_query := c_query||l_cols_arr(cols_arr_size)||' varchar2(4000) NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
    :P31_QUERY := c_query; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c_query;
END;
```

Running this code gives me the following error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option for Execute PL/SQL Code.  I tried to comment out the execute immediate statement and put the query in a page item and it looks like this:

CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_view (Criteria_Name varchar2(4000) NULL, CDC_Part_1 varchar2(4000) NULL, CDC_Part_2 varchar2(4000) NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS

This is my first time using execute immediate so I'm wondering if there's something about it that I don't fully understand, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: shouldnt it be using the DEFAULT keyword for NULL values you are trying to use - 
CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_view (Criteria_Name varchar2(4000) DEFAULT NULL, CDC_Part_1 varchar2(4000) DEFAULT NULL, CDC_Part_2 varchar2(4000) DEFAULT NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS

Comment: Good catch, but still showing the same error after making this change

Comment: Do you actually mean `default null` which doesn't really do much, or are you marking them nullable (as opposed to `not null`), which is the default anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `CREATE OR REPLACE` for tables in Oracle; see the syntax diagram [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html).

Without `OR REPLACE` it works:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_view (Criteria_Name varchar2(4000) NULL, CDC_Part_1 varchar2(4000) NULL, CDC_Part_2 varchar2(4000) NULL) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ksiooi3_)

But creating objects on the fly isn't generally a good idea, or necessary. It's unclear what you're using this for so there might well be better options. If you are going to go down this route then you will need to drop the table at some point, and probably do a protective drop before trying to recreate it each time. If multiple users are connected to the same schema then you will still have problems with this though.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the help, to answer your question as to what this is being used for I'm trying to create a grid view in apex where users can select items from a checkbox group and a "table" is created where the boxes they checked are the column headers.  The problem is the checkbox group is a dynamic list so selecting columns from a pre-existing table wouldn't be possible.  It's definitely a very weird request and if you need a more clear explanation I can provide it for you.

Comment: @Zander - Unless there is only one user in the system that needs this page, it is unlikely that this approach is going to work.  Global temporary tables are global so the object is visible to every session.  If your session creates a temp table and my session goes to create a temp table, my session will get an error that the table already exists.  If I do a drop & create, my session will drop your table so if you query the table you were expecting, you'd see the table definition created by my session.   It sounds like you really want a report based on a dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: Yes I do want exactly that, but where do I select the columns in this report from?  The entire problem I am having is that the pool of columns that this dynamic report will select from changes frequently.

Comment: Maybe you can open and return a ref cursor using a dynamic query instead? The caller would need to interrogate it (or use the same checkboxes I suppose) to get the data and headers in the format you want, perhaps.

Comment: Oracle APEX applications are stateless, that means that there can be many database sessions during the lifespan of an APEX application session. The data in a global temporary table is only visible in a single database session. Global temporary tables are not a good idea for this problem.

Comment: Have you considered the use of APEX Collections?